# Should I migrate all my application's components into GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

My application has it's backend and it's frontend. The frontend is currently hosted in a Google Cloud Storage bucket and I am migrating the backend from Compute Engine VMs to Kubernetes Engine Autopilot.

When migrating, does it make more sense for me to migrate everything to Kubernetes Engine or would I be better off keeping the frontend in the bucket? Backend and frontend are different projects in different git repositories.

I am asking because I saw that it is possible to manage Kubernetes services' exposure, even at the level of URL Maps and Load Balancer, so I thought of perhaps entrusting all my projects' (backend and frontend) hosting to Kubernetes, since I know that Kubernetes is a very complete and powerful solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't problem to keep your front on Cloud Storage (or elsewhere) and to have your backend on kubernetes (GKE).

It's not a "perfect pattern" because you can't handle and deploy all the part of  your application only with Kubernetes and you haven't a end to end control plane management.

You have, one side to deploy your frontend and to configure your load balancer. On the other hand, you have to deploy your backend on Kubernetes with YAML.

In addition, your application is not portable on other kubernetes cluster (because it's not full kubernetes deployment, but hybrid between Kubernetes and Google Cloud, and you are partly sticky to Google Cloud). But if it's not a requirement, it's fine.

---

At the end, if you expose your app behind a load balancer with the front on Cloud Storage and the back on GKE, the user will see nothing. If a day, you want to package your front in a container and deploy it on GKE, keep the same load balancer (at least the same domain name) and you user won't notice the difference!!

No worry for now, you can keep going! (and it's cheaper for now! You don't pay processing to serve static resource with Cloud Storage)

Comment: Thanks. Fully clarified. I just wasn't sure about the conventions and standards/patterns, but you clarified it well. Thanks.